# Simple vector program error

Tags: c++, vector, instantiation

Hi iam new to c++ and iam trying out this vector program and i am getting the following error:
error: conversion from `test*' to non-scalar type`test' requested|

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class test{

    string s;
    vector <string> v;
    public:
    void read(){
        ifstream in ("c://test.txt");
        while(getline(in,s))
        {
             v.push_back(s);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
        {
        cout<<v[i]<<"\n";
        }
    }

};
int main()
{
    cout<<"Opening the file to read and displaying on the screen"<<endl;
    test t=new test();
    t.read();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` is used to dynamically allocate memory. You don't need to do that, so just do:

```
test t; // create an instance of test with automatic storage
t.read(); // invoke a method
```

The error is because the type of `new test()` is a `test*`, a pointer to a (newly created) `test`. You can't assign a `test*` to a `test`.

---

The pointer version, for what it's worth, would have been:

```
test* t = new test();
t->read(); // the arrow is short for (*test).
delete t; // don't forget to clean up!
```

However, it's bad style to do raw memory allocation like that. You'd use something called a smart pointer to make sure it gets deleted automatically, instead. The standard library has one in the header `<memory>`, called `auto_ptr`, that would suffice:

```
std::auto_ptr<test> t(new test()); // put a new test into a pointer wrapper
t->read(); // treat it like a normal pointer
// nothing else to worry about, will be deleted automatically
```

However, all this isn't needed for you, in this case. Always prefer automatic (stack) allocation over dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
test t=new test();
t.read();
```

to

```
test *t=new test();
t->read();
```

`t` should be a pointer to type `test`. And to access a `class` member using a `pointer` we use the `->` operator. Also its a good practice to delete any dynamically allocated objects as:

```
delete t;
```

Answer (score 1):

new test() will return a pointer to a t so you either want to use pointer throuought or create t on the stack

Code using pointers

```
test *t=new test();
t->read();    // note needs -> rather than .
delete t;   // as declared n the heap you must delete
```

or usually better do all on the stack

```
test t;
t.read();
```

Comment: Also note: if you do use <code>new</code>, then you have to make sure to <code>delete(t)</code> after. But as has been said, you really don't need to allocate a new <code>test</code> on the heap; just make one on the stack.